# How to authenticate Flask web app with Azure Active Directory using a self-signed certificate from Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have created a self-signed certificate in Azure Key Vault, and I would like to use it to authenticate my Flask web app in Azure Active Directory.

I started by using a local certificate instead of a one in Azure Key Vault, and it works fine. See the code below

```
cert_file_path = "app/cert.pem"
key_file_path = "app/key.pem"

with open(cert_file_path, "rb") as cert_file:
    cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read(), default_backend())
    cert_thumbprint = cert_obj.fingerprint(hashes.SHA1()).hex()

with open(key_file_path, "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,  # replace with your password if the key is encrypted
        backend=default_backend()
    )

client_credential = {
    "private_key": private_key.private_bytes(
        serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        serialization.NoEncryption()
    ).decode("utf-8"),
    "thumbprint": cert_thumbprint,
}

load_dotenv()
tenant_id = os.getenv('AZURE_TENANT_ID')
client_id = os.getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_ID')
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"

msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_credential,
)

server = Flask(__name__)
server.secret_key = os.environ.get("FLASK_SECRET_KEY")
server.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(server.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)

@server.route("/login")
def login():
    auth_url = msal_app.get_authorization_request_url(["User.Read"])
    return redirect(auth_url)

@server.route("/login/azure/authorized")
def auth():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    result = None
    if code:
        result = msal_app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code, ["User.Read"], redirect_uri=url_for("auth", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return f"Login failure: {result['error']} - {result['error_description']}"
        if "access_token" in result:
            session["user_info"] = result["id_token_claims"]
            return redirect("/")
    return "No code provided. Login failed."
```

However, I am not sure how to use the certificate in Azure Key Vault to do something similar to above?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [self-signed certificate with Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-scenarios) that you download locally and then upload as you did with your local certificate.

You can automate certificate rotation using [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) and Azure Function or Automation.